# Converter minutos em horas

Tags: php

Preciso converter dois valores de minutos para horas utilizando PHP.

```
valor1 = 278 min
valor2 = 1161 min
```

Comment: Dividir por 60 não resolve?

Comment: Tem esta função pronta aqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563535/convert-number-of-minutes-into-hours-minutes-using-php

Comment: Vou dar -1 porque não pergunta de forma clara o que queria e depois altera a pergunta invalidando respostas feitas.

Comment: A pergunta era esta: "Olá, preciso converter dois valores de minutos para horas utilizando PHP."

Comment: @PauloRamos Pois eh. Faz uma pergunta de uma forma, a gente gasta tempo pra responder e depois muda o sentido da pergunta. É a mesma coisa que perguntar: "_Como faz sanduíche com pão e hamburguer?_".. aí depois muda: "_Com pão, hamburguer e presunto?_"... lastimável

Comment: Quando te pedem que horas são? Vc responde somente a hora, ou responde os minutos tbm?

Comment: Não é o caso. Estamos falando de programação.

Comment: Se vc tiver outra pergunta com o que vc quer, vc pode fazer, não há problema algum nisso. Vc não pode é mudar o sentido da pergunta.

Comment: Enfim, não quero saber somente a hora. Acredito q seja dúvida minha e de muitos neste fórum. Transformar minutos em h:i pesquisei em diversos fóruns... Todos sem solução. Peco desculpas se não fui claro, mas a ideia desde o início era está.

Comment: Vc não pediu minutos, pediu horas. Está bem claro na pergunta. Se se equivocou, tudo bem, não há problema, mas não pode mudar a pergunta invalidando respostas já feitas.

Comment: Vc poderia alterar a pergunta caso não houvessem respostas. É normal a gente se enganar, mas neste caso depois de 4 horas alterar a pergunta quando há respostas, não é possível. Se vc queria em h:m, tem uma resposta aí que lhe atente bem.

Comment: Ok poderia indicar qual delas?

Comment: Só tem duas respostas. A minha e de outro usuário.

Comment: Nenhuma resposta resolve os valores de minutos para horas. Irei abrir um novo questionamento.

Comment: Uai, então por que marcou a resposta? A gente só marca a resposta quando ela resolve o problema. Quando não resolve, vc pode questionar nos comentários da resposta.

Comment: Resolveu o questionamento que fiz, nao aquele editado.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$minutos_totais = 278;
$horas = floor($minutos_totais / 60);
$minutos = $minutos_totais % 60;

php > $minutos_totais = 1439;
php > echo floor($minutos_totais / 60);
23
php > echo $minutos_totais % 60;
59
```

Comment: Teste dessa maneira e não funcionou, coloquei em minutos totais 1439, que teria que retornar 23:59 minutos no caso, retornou 59.

Comment: @arllondias Sua crítica não parece fazer sentido pra mim, uma vez que o entendimento padrão de "converter minutos para horas" é justamente pegar uma quantidade X de minutos e devolver uma quantidade Y de horas. Portanto 1439 minutos são 23 horas. De qualquer forma o Victor já mostrou também o cálculo para saber quais os "minutos restantes".

Comment: @LINQ tem razão, antes da pergunta ser editada, me confundi e imprimi apenas o resultado da variável minutos. foi apenas falta de atenção, tudo certo.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo enunciado da pergunta, a intenção é converter a quantidade de minutos em horas, e não retornar *horas* e *minutos*.

O correto seria apenas fazer a divisão dos minutos por 60, retornando o valor em horas com decimais (caso o valor não seja múltiplo de 60):

```
<?php
$valor1 = 278;
$valor2 = 1161;

// arredondando para 2 casas decimais
$valor1 = round($valor1 / 60, 2); // retorna 4.63
$valor2 = round($valor2 / 60, 2); // retorna 19.35
?>
```

Ou seja, **278 minutos** equivale a **4,63 horas**, e **1161 minuto**s a **19,35 horas**.

Caso não queira as decimais (o *resto* que não completou 1 hora):

```
<?php
$valor1 = 278;
$valor2 = 1161;

// arredondando para 2 casas decimais
$valor1 = floor($valor1 / 60); // retorna 4
$valor2 = floor($valor2 / 60); // retorna 19
?>
```

Comment: Não resolve esta última, se for somar os dois passam de 24:00.

Comment: @LucasSpielmann Tudo bem, foi apenas um complemento ao primeiro exemplo.

Comment: Preciso que convertendo os min p horas, exiba horas e minutos em formato de h:i. Somando os dois valores totaliza 23:59

Comment: @LucasSpielmann Entendi. Mas a pergunta não diz isso.

Comment: @LucasSpielmann A pergunta só diz _converter minutos em horas_